# SourceRectangle seems to be distorting the image

Tags: c#, xna

I'm loading in a large image(1500x1000) into a texture. My graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth/Height is 800x600. I'm setting the drawRectangle to be the same size as the large image.

As the mouse moves towards the edges of the screen I have it scroll across the map by having the sourceRectangle change its x, and y coordinates. This all seems to be working great, but my picture is distorted. If I remove the sourceRectangle and just use the normal drawRectangle then it isn't distorted, is there something I'm missing?

```
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture2D pic;
    Rectangle mapRectangle;
    Rectangle mapSourceRectangle;


    public Game1()
        : base()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
        IsMouseVisible = true;
    }
```

...

```
pic = Content.Load<Texture2D>("map");
        mapRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, pic.Width, pic.Height);
        mapSourceRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth, graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight);
```

and then finally when i draw it.

```
spriteBatch.Draw(pic, mapRectangle, mapSourceRectangle, Color.White);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what is happening is mapSourceRectangle is sourcing only a 800 x 600 section of the texture to use as the source then blowing it up to 1500,1000 using mapRectangle (destination) which should be the position in screen space. By removing sourceRectangle it uses the whole image at the correct size.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433987.aspx

destinationRectangle:

A rectangle that specifies (in screen coordinates) the destination for drawing the sprite. If this rectangle is not the same size as the source rectangle, the sprite will be scaled to fit.

Comment: ok cool, i ended up getting it solved tonight by using a Vector2 as the second argument that I passed in rather than a drawRectangle and sourceRectangle. So I guess the vector acts as an offset which is all i needed anyway. It works great now.